# How do I get contacts from an outlook addin taskpane without active sign-in of user?

Tags: javascript, outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am currently developing a taskpane outlook add-ins based on office-js and would be glad if someone could provide some help.

The add-ins are supposed to get the contacts of the current user and compare them to the recipients of the email that is currently written.

I have worked my way through a bunch of resources and have read quite a lot of similar questions, but still cannot figure out how to handle everything combined.

My problem is:
How do I get the contacts from inside an outlook taskpane?

I figured that I have to use the Graph API to get the contacts. I also achieved to register the app and get an APP ID. 
I followed these instructions [Write a JavaScript single-page app to get Outlook mail, calendar, and contacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/javascript-tutorial) and was able to retrieve the contacts inside a browser window.

But I am unable to figure out how all of these parts are supposed to connect in a taskpane add-ins.

Could someone please provide an explanation with actual code examples (and not just links to office docs) on how to get the contacts?

Comment: You can use REST APIs from Addins to get contacts. Please checkout these links: (1) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/use-rest-api (2) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/contacts-rest-operations#GetContacts

Comment: Thanks for doing exactly the opposite of what I wrote in my question. Apart from that I would like to get an access token without having to save the item (which is needed for getCallbackTokenAsync()). Any idea for this?

Comment: Yes, we are aware about "save item" requirement for "REST" token in getCallbackTokenAsync(). We have fixed this so that "save item" won't be a requirement for getting "REST" token in getCallbackTokenAsync(). You can check it in latest production in outlook for web.